# Pidgin will not open with upgrade to 12.04

Tags: pidgin

Clicking on the icon does nothing.  When I try to open it from the command-line I get this error:

```
pidgin: symbol lookup error: pidgin: undefined symbol: purple_dbus_get_connection
```

I have updated and upgraded everything.  I had this same issue in Ubuntu 10.04 which required me to purge the Pidgin PPA and downgrade all of the Pidgin dependencies.  How can this be fixed?

- I ran `sudo ldconfig` and tried to run it again but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your library which is not linked properly.

Open terminal and run `sudo ldconfig`.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: This also does nothing.. I get the same error message

Comment: Try uninstalling pidgin and run `ldconfig` then install/compile pidgin

Comment: this doesn't work either...  I still get the same message